# Is their any equivalent of glDrawTexiOES (OES_draw_texture) under opengl 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I just discover that `glDrawTexiOES` (`OES_draw_texture`) (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt is not available under opengl 2.0 (only in opengl 1.1). Is their any equivalent under opengl 2.0 ? If not what else is the most fastest way under opengl 2.0 to draw a texture without any transformation (like we could do with glDrawTexiOES) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in opengl 2.0.

The fastest way is to use shaders and texture a quad. It might be faster if you omit transformations in the shaders as instructions count and required memory transfers decreases. In practice I doubt there will be a measurable difference.